# webpack external config not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm working React Project when I compile I get the following error

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'config' in '/Users/mirasmith/Desktop/KPV1-Project-master/src/_services'

but follow that tutorial from [Jason Watmore](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example)

I had followed the tutorial correctly but don't if I'm missing anything. I'm trying to create a User Registration and Login they.

I don't know if they are talking about the webpack file that I have added to the development environment. I have created but nothing happens still the same results.

user.service.js

```
import config from 'config';
import { authHeader } from '../_helpers';

export const userService = {
    login,
    logout,
    register,
    getAll,
    getById,
    update,
    delete: _delete
};

function login(username, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

            return user;
        });
}

function logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
}

function getAll() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function getById(id) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function register(user) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/register`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function update(user) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${user.id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);;
}

// prefixed function name with underscore because delete is a reserved word in javascript
function _delete(id) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                logout();
                window.location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        return data;
    });
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
    })],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    externals: {
        // global app config object
        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
        })
    }
}
```

https://gyazo.com/3b45f2c867e3623900f35cd7c149a112[image]

Comment: If anyone runs into this issues don't forget to download an npm package called config --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/config